# How to build new expression to test out result of previous expression without compiling?

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

```
//IsCellDataValid Method returns bool
MethodInfo isCellDataValidMethod = this.GetType().GetMethod("IsCellDataValid", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

var IsCellDataValidMethodCall = Expression.Call(ruleEngineInstance, isCellDataValidMethod, new ParameterExpression[] { method params});

var cellDataValidConstantExp = ConstantExpression.IsTrue(IsCellDataValidMethodCall);

//GetCellTypeCount returns Int
var isCellDataValidExpression = Expression.IfThen(cellDataValidConstant,
                                                  GetCellTypeCountMethodCall);
```

Now I want to compare the output of this `cellTypeCountExpression` to a user entered value and don't want the expression to be compiled to get the result and then build a `Constant Expression`

I have something like

```
var resultBinaryExp = ParameterExpression.LessThan(GetCellTypeCountMethodCall, 
                               Expression.Constant(userEnteredValu), typeof(int));
```

Comment: What is `onCellDataValid` supposed to represent? The way you have written it it's equivalent to `var onCellDataValid = IsCellDataValidMethodCall` at best (at worst the `as` produces a `null` value). That's an expression that evaluates to a boolean. How is it related to anything that counts things?

Comment: you didn't notice the `IfTrue` call ? onCellDataValid will hold `GetCellTypeCountMethodCall` as a `MethodCallExpression` and I guess from my problem I need to use the `ConstantExpression.IsTrue` let me try and post back.

Comment: I have edited the code and tested it works without exception, is there anyother way I can do this ?

Comment: I did notice the `.IfTrue`. `Expression.IfThen(a, b).IfTrue` is the same thing as simply `a`. So what were you trying do achieve?

Comment: No... `IfTrue` returns `b` if `a` is executed to `true`

Comment: I made a small mistake -- it's not `a`, it's `b` (but that does not change the idea). You are wrong, `IfTrue` does not return `b` if `a` evaluates to `true` -- it cannot do that, because it cannot evaluate `a`. These are expression trees, not runnable code. It returns `b` unconditionally.

Comment: Proof: `Console.WriteLine(Expression.IfThen(Expression.Constant(false), Expression.Constant(42)).IfTrue)` prints the "42" expression.

Comment: Why don't you want to compile the expression? I think that's the best way to do this.

Comment: @Jon what I meant was `b` is a placeholder expression that I want executed(when `IsCellDataValidMethodCall` returns `true`) when I finally compile the expression after Building the entire expression tree.